Is natural language incomplete?
I am pretty sure the “lexical hypothesis” is that the data of natural language is “representative” of whatever “world” (metaphysical, ontological) we live in. There are actually influential scientific ideas based on this, like the five factor model of personality in psychology, which is the result of running a clustering algorithm on a corpus (I think).
I’m fascinated by arguments both in favor of and refuting this idea.
Clearly, a priori, natural language cannot be representative of “the entire world”, because there remain concepts we haven’t yet discovered; for example, quantum mechanics was one such “ontological structure”.
Also, I have read some critiques of clustering algorithms, as they may mislead you because they can cluster data in various ways, so it doesn’t mean those clusters are the “absolute” way of organizing data.
On the other hand, ideas from category theory make me think that there can sometimes be a perfect correspondence between “internal structure” and “external structure”. So for example, with LLMs, people commonly say that even though they can identify patterns in the co-occurrence of words, this does not mean they understand what they are talking about, and this can be made evident in certain scenarios where it becomes clear they do not have good and accurate internal representations of the things they are talking about. Some people have countered that with a large enough neural network and training data, the algorithms actually can, and do, using inductive inference, generate accurate models of phenomena, because the structure of those phenomena is actually implicit in the linguistic data.
So the question becomes: does natural language underdetermine a depiction of the world, or can we be pleasantly surprised to find that the external relationships between words actually richly encodes the internal structure of concepts and their relationships to one another?

In what sense? It is not a formal system.

Asides: I don't think you can say that LLMs have any "internal representations of the things they are talking about". What is interesting to me is that LLMs clearly to a large extent understand how to use language meaningfully, without any kind of special representations (apart from their parameters). Imo this means that a lot of classical theories of meaning -- that have representations as core -- are shown to be unneeded. Also, it seems incorrect to say that LLMs use any kind of "inductive inference" - unless in some epiphenomal sense. Pattern recognition is not based on induction.

As a former ML engineer I'm tempted to say: Don't talk to philosophers (or your own inner philosopher) about this. It's just not worth the time and effort :) Just investigate -- by tinkering with corpus, training, model architectures, task definitions, dialogue system -- to what extent particular concepts are or are not fully grasped by the dialogue system. I believe this is essentially an empirical/engineering question (yes, also has obvious ethical aspects but we're not talking about that now). I don't see much value in generalizations here.

Yeah, that line about LLMs using inductive inference really sticks out like a sore thumb. Maybe even worth editing out of the question?

No natural language is complete over even simple theories like the natural numbers, by the standard results of Gödel and Tarski. Could you refine the question? It meanders somewhat.

My money is on incomplete. See this counting argument

There is more than one natural language, and some of them lack words found in others, so at the very least, some are "less complete". Generalize and guess whether even one natural language might happen to be perfect? Yeah, no.

Reminiscent of so-called Sapir–Whorf hypothesis, today quite disregarded. At a general level of understanding, of course language IS2 “representative” of whatever “world” we live in. This is confirmed everyday by our use of it. Of course, we have a lot of issue with this general picture.
